# How can I register my NFTs on opensea

Tags: solidity, truffle, nft, bsc, opensea

I have created **ERC721** contract on **BSC Mainnet** and minted few NFTs, but i don't know how i can see them on *opensea*, i tried this on **rinkeby** it worked perfect, I could see all my NFTs there on *testnets.opensea*.. but in case of **BSC Mainnet** don't know if i have to register my contract/NFTs there or i have to do something else before so that they can appear on opensea.

Need help on how to make my **NFT assets** minted on **BSC Network** appear on *opensea*

Thank you so much in advance!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Opensea did not supports the BSC network. But you can mint the NFTs on Polygon for cheaper fees. Polygon is supported by Opensea platform.

Reference: [Which blockchains does OpenSea support?](https://support.opensea.io/hc/en-us/articles/4404027708051-Which-blockchains-does-OpenSea-support-)